# C# 4.0 Serialization of List<Customer>

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, .net-4.0, xml-serialization

In C# 4.0, I have a standard object, called "Customer" It has properties and a public empty constructor.

I need to serialize a generic `List<Customer>` to XML so I can save it, then load it up and deserialize it back.

Is there now framework support for this that is simpler than it was in .NET 2.0 ?

Comment: There is no change in the XML Serializer between the two releases. What did you find difficult before? There is also a DataContractSerializer, which you may find easier.

Comment: If I remember correctly, DataContractSerializer is a pain because it's picky about element order whereas XMLSerializer isn't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's what I use in my library of goodies:

```
public static string SerializeAsXml<TSource>(object element) where TSource : new()
{
    return SerializeAsXml<TSource>(element, new Type[] {});
}

public static string SerializeAsXml<TSource>(object element, Type[] extraTypes) where TSource : new()
{
    var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(TSource), extraTypes);
    var output = new StringBuilder();
    using (StringWriter writer = new XmlStringWriter(output))
    {
        serializer.Serialize(writer, element);
    }
    return output.ToString();
}

public static TDestination Deserialize<TDestination>(string xmlPath) where TDestination : new()
{
    return Deserialize<TDestination>(xmlPath, new Type[] { });
}

public static TDestination Deserialize<TDestination>(string xmlPath, Type[] extraTypes) where TDestination : new()
{
    using (var fs = new FileStream(xmlPath, FileMode.Open))
    {
        var reader = XmlReader.Create(fs);
        var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(TDestination), extraTypes);
        if (serializer.CanDeserialize(reader))
        {
            return (TDestination)serializer.Deserialize(reader);
        }
    }
    return default(TDestination);
}
```

Not *super* simple, but it works. Note this deserializes from a path only, but you could easily change it to deserialize from a string, just strip out the `FileStream`.

The `XmlStringWriter` looks like:

```
public class XmlStringWriter : StringWriter
{

    public XmlStringWriter(StringBuilder builder)
        : base(builder)
    {

    }

    public override Encoding Encoding
    {
        get { return Encoding.UTF8; }
    }

}
```

I'm simply forcing UTF8 encoding on the XML output.

Comment: Cory, can you include the XmlStringWriter as well.

Comment: -1: Cory, I'm downvoting because this code passes XML as a string. Not a good practice at all.

Comment: I am interested to hear why it is a bad idea? What should you use instead?

Comment: @John: For serialization, what would you rather it did? This particular helper class is in an application that generates XML markup as part of a DAO wrapper, I'd be happy to learn better techniques!

Comment: @Cory: I'd prefer it pass an `XmlReader`, or XElement, or XmlDocument - something that actually represents XML. A string could be anything, and often is. I'm trying to keep people out of the habit of creating things like `string person = "<person name='" + this.Name + "'/>";` See any problem with that code?

Comment: @John: I agree, but I'm not sure where you're seeing that I'm passing any elements as a string. The string parameter in the `Deserialize<TDestination>` method takes a string, but it's a file path. I might argue that the `Serialize<TSource>` method should't take an `object` but an instance of `TSource`.

Comment: @Cory: `SerializeAsXml` returns `string`

Answer (score 3):

The framework support for this is [XmlSerializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlserializer.aspx), which is mostly unchanged, but very easy to use.

Answer (score 2):

Linq has XML support, but IMO the `System.Xml.Serialization` way is quite simple. Write a class with public properties, and if it's simple enough you don't even need to annotate it. Just make a serializer and use a stream on it, and you're done.

Answer (score 0):

Serialize (convert an object instance to an XML document):

```
// Assuming obj is an instance of an object
XmlSerializer ser = new XmlSerializer(obj.GetType());
System.Text.StringBuilder sb = new System.Text.StringBuilder();
System.IO.StringWriter writer = new System.IO.StringWriter(sb);
ser.Serialize(writer, obj);
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.LoadXml(sb.ToString());
```

Deserialize (convert an XML document into an object instance):

```
//Assuming doc is an XML document containing a serialized object and objType is a System.Type set to the type of the object.
XmlNodeReader reader = new XmlNodeReader(doc.DocumentElement);
XmlSerializer ser = new XmlSerializer(objType);
object obj = ser.Deserialize(reader);
// Then you just need to cast obj into whatever type it is eg:
MyClass myObj = (MyClass)obj;
```

You can also try msdn tutorial
[Serialization (C# and Visual Basic)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms233843.aspx)